# MappingStragety to write a field of type hashMap

Tags: java, opencsv

I'm using opencsv for read/write csv files using opencsv annotations.
My bean is having fields not just primitives, but a java `HashMap` as well.
Now what i want to do is

```
public class MyBean {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "ID")
    private int id;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "PROPERTIES")
    private Map<String, String> sampleMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

TO

```
ID, property1, property2...
1, value1, value2.....
```

I'd like to get this working in both read/write.

as i understand, the default MappingStrategy doesn't work in this case. Also Creating Custom MappingStrategy doesn't makes sense for `HashMap` field. because we don't know the complete field list until we iterate all the map.

Another way to get column names is that just read one bean from the list of beans. And get access to HashMap then create the header.(Hashmap keys are fixed across beans in my case)

MappingStrategy only concerned about Class level meta data. Like fields etc.

```
public static Field[] getAllFields(Class<?> cls) {
        List allFieldsList = getAllFieldsList(cls);
        return (Field[])allFieldsList.toArray(new Field[allFieldsList.size()]);
    }
```

getting access to the real data for creating csv header doesn't look like a natural way to do.

Any advice on how to solve this?

Please point me out to any other libraries out there that can do read/write into beans having `Map` field.

Cheers!

Comment: To be precise, i don't have a csv file yet. So writing is my first step.
Map<String,List<String>>..Could  you elaborate what that Map contains.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly openCSV does not support this.  A quick google showed me that SuperCSV comes close but it puts everything in a map whereas you want to control what goes in the map and what does not.   There may be others out there but most require a one to one between the fields in the object and the columns in the csv file.

This was something that I wanted to develop for years and contribute because the company I currently work for has need for that but they do not want to pay me to develop it and I have higher priorities for openCSV when free time is available.

A possible but limited workaround would be to create what I would call a Data Transfer Object.  Have a custom object that has all the values you would have and have it return the object of the type you want (or a translator that will convert the DTO that has all fields to the object you want with the map and some fields).  The problem with this solution is that it forces you to know in advance what are all possible entries you have in the map.